# Quando usar And, AndAlso e Or, OrElse?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lógica, booleano

Não sei quando usar as sintaxes `Or` ou `OrElse` e/ou `And` ou `AndAlso`, pois não entendo que diferença isso faz no circuito lógico.

Sendo em C#, `And` = `&`, `AndAlso` = `&&` e `Or` = `|`, `OrElse` = `||`.

Preciso testar a seguinte expressão para saber se o inteiro `lastToken` é zero (0) **e também** se é maior que 2:

```
if(lastToken == 0 & lastToken > 2) { ... }
```

Mas não sei se uso `&` ou `&&`.

Qual devo usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa Tarde.

& e && são as mesmas comparações, entretanto:

Se você tem uma **Expressão1** & **Expressão2**, ele vai checar as duas, logo você vai gastar mais tempo.

Se você tem **Expressão1** *&&* **Expressão2**, ele vai checar a primeira e somente vai checar a segunda se a primeira for verdadeira.

Se estiver estudando, use qualquer uma, mas vai chegar um momento que a velocidade do seu código vai influenciar.

Or e OrElse segue a mesma lógica.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, `&` verifica as duas expressões, se as duas forem `true`, a expressão em si é verdadeira, se uma for false, a expressão é false?

Comment: Sim, e isso pode ocasionar perda de tempo.

Logicamente se uma expressão com AND tiver pelo menos uma False, não precisa checar a outra, por isso existe o &&, ele checa a primeira e acaba lá mesmo se for falsa.

Comment: Esqueceu-se de referir que `&` é um operador de aritmética enquanto `&&` é um operador lógico. A expressao `21 & 1` é válida mas a expressao `21 && 1` nao é válida.

Comment: Eu particularmente não gosto de usar o operador `&` (que para mim sempre vai se chamar `bitwise-and`) se não for uma operação que eu saiba de antemão que eu vou fazer operações nos bits. Tipo, quando eu quero que `3 & 1` seja verdadeiro e `6 & 1` seja falso